# Using kafka streams to extract information from logs contained in a kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

This is one of my first attemp to kafka streams. 
I've correctly created a topic with my logs that looks like this :

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic example --from-beginning
{"event":"bank.user.patch","ts":"2017-05-11T15:02:53.647+02:00","svc":"dpbank.wb.tlc-1","request":{"ts":"2017-05-11T15:02:53.905+02:00","aw":"c0dc73ae-e903-43c2-bba8-2138d7772945","end_point":"/bank/v1/user/Nqp0a++O4wEKgBCMs35GTw==","method":"PATCH","app_instance":"85164F62-91FA-4FF4-BE8E-1C0BA8F291A9-1488367268","user_agent":"Dy/1.1/iOS/10.1.1/iPhone MDL","user_id":423,"user_ip":"xxxxx","username":"booWlWuCPPltvQgMNiKwrQ==","app_id":"db2ffe87712530981e9871","app_name":"DApp"},"operation":{"scope":"mdpapp","result":{"http_status":200}},"resource":{"object_id":"Ns35GTw==","request_attributes":{"user":{"msisdns":"rTA4G5+h9YA==","selfie":false,"taxcode":"Qz96apGFHlQoV/VtGrJDzZpt6cN4mTxSZs1pEI="}},"response_attributes":{"user":{"sharing_id":"NqpCMs35GTw==","msisdns":"Zsd/v08t6hU9AQV8zXna9Ypv/JITMZj3ulGw=","msisdn_caller":"booWlWuCPPltrQ==","selfie":false,"taxcode":"apGFHlQoV/VtGrJDzZpt6cN4mTxWd+K5SZs1pEI","status":"INCOMPLETE","document_info":{"document_image":false}}}},"class":"DPAPI"}
{"event":"bank.user.patch","ts":"2017-04-07T17:42:31.035+02:00","svc":"dpbank.wb.tlc-1","request":{"ts":"2017-04-07T17:42:31.353+02:00","aw":"99c57-8598-b226af153ab9","end_point":"/ba19XFUV+FA==","method":"PATCH","app_instance":"3558887f-7480-4176-b96c-d989ef1a7aa5-1489492341","user_agent":"Drodroid/5.0.1/Samsung-SM-N910C","user_id":398,"user_ip":"151.14.81.82","username":"dNGqxhJ+4kmmF1h3hgu=","app_id":"db2ffeac6c07712530981e9871","app_name":"DropPayApp"},"operation":{"scope":"mdpapp","result":{"http_status":200}},"resource":{"object_id":"KJl+60+x67JFUV+FA==","request_attributes":{"user":{"sharing_id":"KJl+T619XFUV+FA==","msisdns":[],"firstname":"gR47acZfexoW+HYA==","lastname":"h3gRVpNzavhNu4wQ==","gender":"M","selfie":false,"taxcode":"2INKXPiBeg5acM4nn04S+JrlgJ9rmYHNghUw=","status":"INCOMPLETE","birthinfo":{"city":"Zurigo","date":"1975-06-16","country_id":241},"residence":{"city":"CAIA","address":"Va ello 44","zipcode":"926","country_id":1,"city_id":123}}},"response_attributes":{"user":{"sharing_id":"KJl+60+x67JT619XFUV+FA==","msisdns":[],"firstname":"gR47acZfHdgSGcexoW+HYA==","lastname":"h3MyQR3YgRVpNzavhNu4wQ==","gender":"M","selfie":false,"taxcode":"2INKXPiBeg5acM4nn04S+JrllI6mH2YgJ9rmYHNghUw=","status":"INCOMPLETE","birthinfo":{"city":"Zurigo","date":"1975-06-16","country_id":1},"residence":{"city":"TANIA","address":"Vlo 44","zipcode":"926","country_id":18,"city_id":103},"document_info":{"document_image":false}}}},"class":"DPAPI"}
```

Now I'm trying to use this topic to do some logic.

For instance, I'd like to take some fields of every single log in my topic and put them like in a `Ktable` and then send them somewhere else.

I've tried to do this but unfortunately with no results

So far this is what I've done:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-userstate");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 0);

        // setting offset reset to earliest so that we can re-run the demo code with the same pre-loaded data

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

        KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();

        KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream("example");
```

then I tried the Ktable which it should be my "table" containing some fields taken from the logs.

```
KTable<String, Long> counts = source.print();

        // need to override value serde to Long type
        counts.to("example-output");
```

Just to see if the logic is correct and see if I correctly take the logs and put them in another "output" topic. But doing this I got a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`...

Am I in the right path? What should I do in order to correctly read from the kafka topic and extract some fields and put them in a Ktable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, it would help if you actually showed the full exception -- why and where did you get the `NullPointerException`?

> Am I in the right path? What should I do in order to correctly read from the kafka topic and extract some fields and put them in a Ktable?

Your general approach is ok but it looks like your code has a few mistakes.  For example:

```
KTable<String, Long> counts = source.print();
```

`print()` returns `void`, so the line above does not even compile.  Perhaps you should double-check whether your answer is actually containing all the relevant information?

I'd recommend to take a look at the many examples and demo applications available at https://github.com/confluentinc/examples.  They should give you some templates to use as a starting point.